# csvtojson how to add rownumber

Tags: javascript, node.js, csvtojson

Novice in node.js here. I am using `csvtojson` to read a csv into an object `fileDataObject`, like that:

```
    const csv=require("csvtojson");
    csv(
        {
            delimiter:mq.delim
            ,trim:false
        }
    )
    .fromFile(mq.folder_pending+'\\'+file)
    .then((fileDataObject)=>{
```

What I'd like is for `fileDataObject` to have an additional "column" (property) named `row_number`, which indicates the source line number of the file.

The documentation mentions something about a [file line hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson#csv-file-line-hook), but I don't know how to use hooks.

Comment: did you mange to console.log `fileDataObject` and see what is it?

Comment: Yes, it is working quite well. Do you need a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an example on the package readme.

Once you get your `fileDataObject` (in your example), you can simply add a column key

For example

```
  const csv=require('csvtojson')
csv()
.subscribe((jsonObj,index)=>{
    jsonObj.myNewKey='some value'
    // OR asynchronously
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        jsonObj.myNewKey='some value'; <-- add column here
        resolve();
    })
})
.on('data',(jsonObj)=>{
    console.log(jsonObj.myNewKey) // some value
});
```

For your example

```
const csv=require("csvtojson");
csv(
    {
        delimiter:mq.delim
        ,trim:false
    }
)
.fromFile(mq.folder_pending+'\\'+file)
.then((fileDataObject)=>{
     //if you already have a javascript object, u can manually do it too.
     let counter = 1;
     const fileDatWithRowNumber = fileDataObject.map( item => {
          item.row_number = counter;
          counter++; 
          return item
     })
     return fileDatWithRowNumber
}
```

Comment: So, the idea is that the row number is the same as the `fileDataObject` array index, right? But can I be sure about that? Could it be that the array might be stored in a mixed order?

Comment: it's the index+1 since index starts from 0. The index will be according to the line number in the file. I don't think there's any reason it may be stored in a mixed order unless you mutate it.